# Sunspot search - ignore default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, acts-as-tenant

I'm using `acts_as_tenant` gem that injects default scope in my models.

I also use Sunspot for search like so:

```
Article.search do 
  with(:organization_id, ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.id)
  fulltext params[:search]
end
```

`Article` model is scoped so that even if I don't pass current tenant id in search I would only get the right results (just the total would be off).

Now, the problem:

If in some situations I want to ignore default scope coming from `acts_as_tenant` how can I do it in Solr? This WILL NOT work:

```
Article.unscoped.search do
  with(:organization_id, 999)
  fulltext params[:search]
end
```

it will generate incorrect SQL:

```
Article Load (34.2ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`id` IN (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32) AND `articles`.`organization_id` = 1
```

where `organization_id` is the current tenant's id

**TL;DR: How do I ignore default scope when searching with Sunspot?**

Answer (score 0):

I still failed to find a way to ignore the default scope when using sunspot that does not involve forking the gem. However I was able to use

```
ActsAsTenant.without_tenant do 
 RUN THE ENTIRE CODE HERE 
end
```

As of today (04 August, 2016) this feature has not yet been released but you can [use git repo directly](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant/issues/140)